# SQL Server doesn't use expected index

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan

I have the following query (simplified from an Entity Framework query, I don't have direct control of the SQL):

```
SELECT TOP 15
HouseHoldingRuns.Id,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ManCoId FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1 GridRuns.Id
        FROM GridRuns
        WHERE HouseHoldingRuns.Id = GridRuns.HouseHoldingRunId
    ) AS [FirstGridRun]
    INNER JOIN Documents ON FirstGridRun.Id = Documents.GridRunId
    ORDER BY Documents.Id
)
FROM HouseHoldingRuns
ORDER BY HouseHoldingRuns.Id
```

Which produces the following plan:

[image: Without hint]
Adding a `WITH (FORCESEEK)` on the Documents table results in the following plan, which performs much better.

[image: With hint]

Why is SQL Server getting it so wrong?  I'm guessing the problem lies in the large difference between estimated and actual rows, but I don't know how to fix that... (I've tried updating all stats and rebuilding indexes).

Note: I don't really want the `ORDER BY Documents.Id` in there, but put it in for Evgeny to see the results of his suggestion.

Comment: Can you capture the query and add to the question please? If nothing else, EF queries can be entertaining to database folk.

Comment: That's a beautiful query...

Comment: Are the statistics up to date?

Comment: Look at your statistics - 50k estimated 4.2 MILLION actual. Investigate that first, that's most likely the problem.

Comment: @datagod - Yeah, also tried rebuilding the indexes.

Comment: @SeanGallardy - Running sp_updatestats reports that no updates were required.

Answer (score 1):

In the version of the query with `FORCESEEK`, the majority of the query cost is in the key lookup. You can eliminate this key lookup by creating a nonclustered index on `GridRunId` and `MancoId`.

Have a look at the estimated cost figure in the `SELECT` (root) node of your plans. The optimizer will chose the plan with the lowest estimated cost. By adding a covering nonclustered index, you eliminate the need for the key lookup. This should make the estimated cost of the index seek less than the index scan. You might also want to run the query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to make sure it uses a fresh execution plan. The index could look something like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GridRunId_MancoId] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [GridRunId] ASC,
    [MancoId] ASC
)
WITH 
(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
)
ON [PRIMARY];
```

The optimizer would ordinarily cost the scan higher than the seek, but the effect of the `TOP` means the optimizer computes costs for the desired number of rows (a ['row goal'](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx)) rather than for the whole set (it estimates that a partial scan will locate the 15 desired rows more efficiently than the seek + lookup combination).